# Why can't deploy containers on k8s cluster on AWS EC2 correctly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, containers, kubectl

When I use AWS EC2 deploy k8s cluster, deploy a test container on it:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment-test
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-test
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: ubuntu
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Got

```
Back-off restarting failed container
Error syncing pod
```

error on pods. When describe the special pod: `kubectl describe pod app-deployment-test-ccddf7bcc-dqltq`, got these messages at tail of the output:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                From                   Message
  ----     ------                 ----               ----                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled              41s                default-scheduler      Successfully assigned app-deployment-test-ccddf7bcc-dqltq to app-instance
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  41s                kubelet, app-instance  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-zrf98"
  Normal   Pulling                14s (x3 over 40s)  kubelet, app-instance  pulling image "ubuntu"
  Normal   Pulled                 12s (x3 over 32s)  kubelet, app-instance  Successfully pulled image "ubuntu"
  Normal   Created                12s (x3 over 31s)  kubelet, app-instance  Created container
  Normal   Started                11s (x3 over 31s)  kubelet, app-instance  Started container
  Warning  BackOff                11s (x3 over 27s)  kubelet, app-instance  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  FailedSync             11s (x3 over 27s)  kubelet, app-instance  Error syncing pod
```

What will be the reason it failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default command](https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile#L32) to ubuntu container is `bash`. This `bash` command will run one time and will stop the container, this is the expected behavior.

If you want to keep the container running add the command and argument below.

`command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done"]`

I recommend you to run the [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) container that will keep running until you kill the container.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just want to use the 'ubuntu' image to do the cluster test. As you said, if use 'nginx' image to do the test will be better.